# Limits of Batch, REST API: how to get 2000+ records, not just 250?

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch, callout, limits

This code works, but I can get only 250 records even if on other side 2000+ records. I think my batch is incorrect. How can I make a few callouts per 1 time to get 2000+ records from service side?
Callout:

```
public class Callout {
public static List<Instrument__c> instrumentsList;

public static HttpRequest createRequestForService(String token){
    HttpRequest finalRequest = new HttpRequest();
    finalRequest.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);
    finalRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    finalRequest.setHeader('accept','application/json');
    finalRequest.setMethod('GET');
    finalRequest.setEndpoint('https://name.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+InstrumentFromService__c');
    return finalRequest;
}

public class WrapperClass {
    public Integer totalSize;
    public Boolean done;
    public String nextRecordsUrl;
    public Instrument__c[] records;
}

public class WebToken{
    public String WEBTOK{get;set;}
}

public static void getResult() {
    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    HttpRequest requestForToken = 'get_right_token_is_here';
    HttpResponse responseToken = ourHttp.send(requestForToken);
    OAuth2 objAuthenticationInfo = (WebToken)JSON.deserialize(responseToken.getbody(), WebToken.class);

    if(objAuthenticationInfo.WEBTOK != null) {
        HttpRequest requestForService = createRequestForService(objAuthenticationInfo.WEBTOK);
        HttpResponse responseService = ourHttp.send(requestForService);
            instrumentsList = ((WrapperClass)JSON.deserialize(responseService.getBody(), WrapperClass.class)).records;
            for(Instrument__c ins : instrumentsList) {
                ins.Id = null;
            }
            return responseService;
    }
    else return null;
}
}
```

Batch:

```
global class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<Integer>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

global Integer operationsQuantity = 1;
global Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    List<Integer> scope = new List<Integer>();
    for(Integer i = 1; i <= operationsQuantity; i++){
        scope.add(i);
    }
    return scope;
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Integer> scope){
    List<Instrument__c> mainList = new List<Instrument__c>();
    for(Integer i : scope){
        HttpResponse res = CalloutResume.getCalloutResponseContents();
        List<Instrument__c> instrumentsList = Callout.instrumentsList;
        mainList.addAll(instrumentsList);
    }
    upsert mainList Name;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
}
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using callouts to retrieve records rather than native SOQL? Second, what is your specific problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I get records from another organisation. How can I do it withot callout? I haven't error. I get ONLY 250 records. Even if on service side it's 2300 records. I need a code to getting thousands records. So I want to make steps, like 100 records per 1 time n times, where n = records_quantity / 100. So that's way I can get more records.

Answer (score 3):

The REST API has a [Query Options Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm), which allows you to specify a maximum size between 200 and 2,000. However, each response payload is also limited in size, so the system automatically reduces the maximum size based on the number and type of fields you query. The default value starts at 2,000, so if you're getting a smaller return size, it means that there are too many fields or too many big fields to use the maximum response size. If you need the fields, then you can't increase the size of the batch. Your only two choices are to reduce the number of fields queried or deal with the fact that you won't be able to query any more records than that at once.

Comment: You wrote earlier: "For replicating millions of records, consider just using a normal query. Unless you're specifically trying to circumvent security/sharing settings, your client can just request the data directly: `/services/data/v44.0/query?q=select+full_name__c+from+item__c` It will include automatic pagination, requires no code, and is a standard function."

Comment: @user60684 I was referring to the far-end code (`/services/apexrest/...`). Obviously you still need to process all the data. You can use a Queueable chain to get all the records, or Batchable, etc. The automatic pagination comes from the REST API in the form of a "nextRecordsUrl", which you just repeatedly callout to until "done" is true.